# Azure Search match against two properties of the same object

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I would like to do a query matches against two properties of the same item in a sub-collection.

Example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Person 1",
    "contacts": [
        { "type": "email", "value": "person.1@xpto.org" },
        { "type": "phone", "value": "555-12345" },
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to be able to search by `emails` than contain `xpto.org` but,
doing something like the following doesn't work:

```
search.ismatchscoring('email','contacts/type,','full','all') and search.ismatchscoring('/.*xpto.org/','contacts/value,','full','all')
```

instead, it will consider the condition in the context of the main object and objects like the following will also match:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Person 1",
    "contacts": [
        { "type": "email", "value": "555-12345" },
        { "type": "phone", "value": "person.1@xpto.org" },
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any way around this without having an additional field that concatenates type and value?

Comment: have you tried moving the first clause (contacts type email) to the filter clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've implemented was creating different collections per contact type.

This way I'm able to search directly in, lets say, the email collection without the need for correlated search. It might not be the solution for all cases but it works well in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw the official doc. At this moment, there's no support for correlated search:

> This happens because each clause applies to all values of its field in
>   the entire document, so there's no concept of a "current sub-document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-understand-collection-filters

Comment: The solution I've implemented was creating different collections per contact type.  
This way I'm able to search directly in, lets say, the email collection without the need for correlated search.